# Elasticsearch - indexing Spanish text - odd results

Tags: elasticsearch

When we index a document through our CMS publishing pipeline, containing Spanish text in the "office_name" field, we've started to see some odd characters appearing:

> ESPAŇA - Servicios de Chárter

Appears as

> ESPAÅ‡A - Servicios de ChÃ¡rter

Our mapping for this field is as follows:

```
"office_name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "fields": {
                     "raw": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               },
```

I've checked the logs in the CMS and I can't see any malforming of the string prior to the indexing command being sent to Elasticsearch.

The weird thing is, if I index a new document directly within Sense, containing just this field and the same text, it goes in fine!

```
PUT publication_36/Pages/9999
{
  "office_name":"ESPAŇA - Servicios de Chárter"
}
```

Searching again returns:

```
 {
    "_index": "publication_36",
    "_type": "Pages",
    "_id": "9999",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
       "office_name": "ESPAŇA - Servicios de Chárter"
    }
 }
```

Can anyone advise on why where seeing this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like `ESPAŇA - Servicios de Chárter` is being stored as a UTF-8 string. the `Ň` and `á` are held in double byte characters.

Elasticsearch doesn't have any problems holding the data - it's Unicode compliant.

I think the problem must be in your CMS - it's treating the data as single byte ASCII instead of UTF-8 (i.e. it's trying to interpret the 2 byes that make up the `Ň` and `á` as separate chars).

Comment: Thanks Olly - to clarify its a small Java class called by our CMS that actually uses the JEST client to send info to Elasticsearch. This class logs its input and the logs show the correct accents prior to actually sending. I've had a dig around the JEST src and it seems like its encoding in UTF-8 to. But I feel ultimately your right - it wont be Elasticsearch mangling the string itself.